# Canvas multiple images and Mobile Browser performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I'm writting about the mobile browser performance with HTML5 canvas. I'm trying to make a simple platform game (like super mario bros). I have a main character, two enemies and blocks imitating jumping platforms. Character and enemies are drawn by drawImage, block are drwn by fillRect (for now, later it will be also drawImage). Everything is animated (when character moves, the character X is added to blocks X and so on).

Now I'm trying to add some random coins.
First I created variable for Image

```
var coinB = new Image();
coinB.src = 'coin.png';
```

Next I'm creating array with objects with random X and Y:

```
var k;
for (k = 0; k <= 30; k++) {
    coins.push({
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 36 + 4) * 100,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1) * 100,
        width:25,
        height:25
    });
}
```

And after that I'm trying to select everything and draw:

```
var l;
/* left is the character X for the animation */
for (l = 0; l < coins.length; l++) {
    ctx.drawImage(coinB, coins[l].x - left, coins[l].y, coins[l].width, coins[l].height);
}
```

Everything is in a function() that is in requestAnimFrame.

Unfortunately after that, game  has about 30fps (from previously 60 fps without coins) on Mobile FireFox (Chrome Mobile 20-30 fps). So it's about half of fps with coins.

Is there a better way to import images and draw them? For example I do the `new Image()` for all thing (mainchar = new Image(), enemy = new Image(), coin = new Image()= ect), the same with `.src`. I assume it's not the best solution.
How should I do, to gain better performance (to lose less fps) ?
Thank you for help.

Comment: What about initialising the coins outside of the main loop? Instantiating objects is not free. You can also optimise the loop with `for(l=0, len=coins.length; i < len;++l)`. You can read about the optmised loop [here](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-length).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience; I have looked for tips and trick, but there are no magic ways to solve the performance problem.
The key to improving performances is reducing the calls to "drawImage" to the absolute minimum... keep in mind that it is the bottleneck of your process!
So, be sure to draw only what is currently visible (i.e. dont draw coins/blocks/background) that are out of the view).

For what concern images loading, I dont see any alternative to what you are currently doing.
The best you can do is using a unique file, containing all the images, and then using the right portion when you need it; this should reduce download times (1 larger files is better than many smaller files), but wont increase performances.

Hope this helped a little, have fun!

Comment: He should have checked your answer, because I see no other way to answer to his question **`;)`**